# How is it possible for new content to appear in Google results mere minutes after it is created?

Tags: indexing, seo

For example, when I post to Stackoverflow, the post appears in the Google index a minute later. How is this accomplished? What do I have to do to my web-site to get the same frequency of indexing?

Answer (score 7):

You could start by:

- getting 65,000-odd regular users on your site.
- making your site linked to from all over the place.
- make your site very active.
- providing *very* useful content.

This is all standard SEO stuff which will up your "importance" in the eyes of Google (and other search engines, presumably, but who cares :-).

Answer (score 5):

The faster a page changes, the more google will re-index it.
Obviously, if your site is "important" enough for google.

You should check out Google Webmaster Tools here http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

Answer (score 1):

To help with indexing from Google, but also Yahoo and MS, you'll want to use the `sitemap` protocol, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps .

Comment: Google will only crawl your site as often as it thinks is worthwhile, regardless of your use of sitemaps.  Sitemaps are useful for helping google find pages that might be too deeply buried to be found via normal crawling, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, if you want do that you, first, need to lure Google robot to you site.

To do this you should do those things:

1. Building as much hyperlinks to high-ranked, active, relevant sites as possible.
2. make your own site active. In this way, google believes your site is worthwhile to visit frequently!

In addition to this, you can provide premier content and structure(site map).

To sum all of them up, you need build a great site in the eyes of search engines!

Good luck!